# Suppress link if condition is met in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to supress a report link when the below condition met

`if {?Format} = "Html" then false else true`

`if {LINE56_TYPECD} = 3 then false else true`

but i'm getting error as

> The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the statement is off. After the first "else true" the statement must stop.

if {?Format} = "Html" then false else true

So rethink the syntax/logic of what you are trying to achieve